# Unifying tuples

Tags: sql, postgresql

I hope I remember SQL and that this is not a silly question...: I have the result of a complex query as a tuple containing two elements, I'd like to obtain a list containing a union of those elements. I'm using Postgresql but I'd like standard SQL

So, I have
select foo which gives as a result

```
(field_1_1, field_1_2),
(field_2_1, field_2_2),
...
```

and I want

```
(field_1_1),
(field_1_2),
(field_2_1),
(field_2_2)
```

How can I do?

Comment: is it a text field?

Comment: yes, it is a text field

Comment: parentheses are included in your result?

Comment: parentheses are there only to represent tuples. So, there is no parentheses in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unnest():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
with my_table (col1, col2) as (
values
    ('f11', 'f12'),
    ('f21', 'f22')
)

select unnest(array[col1, col2])
from my_table;

 unnest 
--------
 f11
 f12
 f21
 f22
(4 rows)
```

or union:

```
select col1
from my_table
union all
select col2
from my_table;
```

Note, that the order of resulting rows is undefined without the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I've used TRIM() function just to remove leading spaces from second element.

There isn't a standard SQL method for this job, each DMBS has specific functions.

> ```
> create table tbl (foo text);
> insert into tbl values
> ('field_1_1, field_1_2'),
> ('field_2_1, field_2_2');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select trim(from split_part(foo, ',', 1)) from tbl
> union 
> select trim(from split_part(foo, ',', 2)) from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | btrim     |
> | :-------- |
> | field_1_1 |
> | field_1_2 |
> | field_2_1 |
> | field_2_2 |
> ```

> ```
> select trim(from unnest(string_to_array(foo, ',')))
> from   tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | btrim     |
> | :-------- |
> | field_1_1 |
> | field_1_2 |
> | field_2_1 |
> | field_2_2 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7f963d27d710b708b2c1dfbf7a531bae)*